# How to measure the latency to a webserver?

Tags: linux, networking, internet, ping, tcp

I wish to measure the TCP network latency from my Linux server, to a websocket URL.

I am using netperf like this:

```
netperf -H ws.the_websocket_url.com -l 5 -t TCP_STREAM -v 2 -- -o min_latency,mean_latency,max_latency
```

However, whatever URL I try (the websocket URL, google.com etc) the command takes forever and eventually replies with:

```
establish_control: are you sure there is a netserver listening on <the address> at port 12865? 
establish_control could not establish the control connection from 0.0.0.0 port 0 address family AF_UNSPEC to <the address> port 12865
```

I haven't used `netperf` before. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Netperf doesn't work with arbitrary HTTP servers. You have to run netperf's "netserver" binary on the target server machine for your test.

Answer (score 0):

`Ping` is a good tool to measure the latency to an IP address or
server address.

It does not require installing software on the target system.

Comment: `sudo apt install mtr`... then e.g. `$ mtr -i 13 server` - then explore e.g. hit the `d` key repeatedly for suitable / interesting settings.